# Spring boot, Spring core dependency

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I run spring boot 1.3.3.RELEASE, I have run into this issue that are solved in spring 4.3 https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18686 (formerly SPR-14114)

When does spring boot support spring 4.3 ? Can I upgrade my spring-core dependency in current version of spring boot that I have.

Answer (score 5):

> When does spring boot support spring 4.3 ?

Spring Boot 1.4 will use Spring Framework 4.3 by default.

> Can I upgrade my spring-core dependency in current version of spring boot that I have.

Yes. Spring Boot 1.3.x uses Spring Framework 4.2.x by default but it is compatible with Spring Framework 4.3.x. Assuming that you are using Maven and `spring-boot-starter-parent` as your pom's parent, you can use the `spring.version` property to control the version of Spring Framework that's used. For example:

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.3.0.RC1</spring.version>
</properties>
```